# Longest Shortest Path (not quite)

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-algorithm, graph-theory

For my bachelor thesis, I have encountered the following problem (solving which could be useful for the actual problem of the thesis). I have a weighted directed graph `G` with vertices `V` and two vertices from `V`, start `s` and destination `t`. I can remove at most `k` vertices. I need to find vertices, the removal of which, would maximize the cost (length) of the shortest path from `s` to `t` in the adjusted graph.

I suppose, this problem should have been addressed before in the literature, however, I did not manage to find relevant articles. I would be grateful for any links to the relevant literature.

Comment: *Longest shortest path ?  What does that mean

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give sample input and output for the problem

Answer (score -1):

You can apply [Yen's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen's_algorithm) to find the shortest K paths. Now how do you apply that in your code? You apply not for the first K paths but for all the paths that have the same length as the shortest. Once you find all of those (K1 as a count) you now take each path and remove (simulate that you remove) one vertex (if you already considered you can skip it) but if not, now you have a problem of Shortest paths in a graph with a skip-able vertex. At each step you try to maximize the 'shortest path' and chose that vertex. I'm thinking of a more optimal way but this is the best I can from the top of my head.

You do K time:

1. Do Yen's algorithm modified as I said.
2. Find the best local solution of remove one vertex to increase the minim distance.